# Build search with filter to search over at least two fields

Tags: python, django

```
class Objects(models.Model):
  name = Charfield
  term = Charfield
```

I have search field where I type like name/term of the object in.
 Is there an easy way to filter for both fields and concat the queryset to present it then as a result.

Or I have to work with checkboxes? To realize this simple

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding your question, you need an `OR` condition, that can be achieved using `Q` objects and `|` operator between them.

```
from django.db.models import Q
Objects.objects.filter(Q(name=search_field_value) | Q(term=search_field_value))
```

where `search_field_value` is a value of the search field.

Also see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).